# I want to plot a scatter plot with 2 separate dictionary keys

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Plotting a scatter plot with 2 separate dictionaries.

```
dict1 = {'A': 6,'B': 3,'C': 2}
dict2 = {'A': 3300.0, 'B': 100.0, 'C': 300.0}
```

I want to get a scatter plot with dict1's values as x-axis, dict2's values as y-axis and with each point labelled A, B and C

I tried:

```
x = list(dict1.keys())
y = list(dict2.keys())
labels = list(dict1.keys())
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

However, i looked into the arguments of plt.scatter(), so i tried

```
plt.scatter(x,y,label=labels)
plt.show()
```

The label didnt show up

Comment: Points are labeled via `plt.annotate`. Also if you want to use the dictionary values on the axes, you need to use `dict.values()`, not `dict.keys()`.

Answer (score 0):

You did it almost.

```
x = list(dict1.values())
y = list(dict2.values())
n = list(dict2.keys())
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Up to this part, you have done it perfect. You have plotted the scatter graph. Now lets get to the annotation part.

So far, the points that are accompanied by the keys of the dictionary (in this case, both keys are same). In order to get the points (as the lists x and y) as well as the keys (as list n) simultenously, we need enumerate() function.

*The enumerate() function takes in an iterable as an argument, such as a list, string, tuple, or dictionary.*

So, for each item (element) and its index (i) in 'n' list, I can annotate the plot's indices (scatter points) with the element. This can be achieved by the following,

```
for i, element in enumerate(n):
    plt.annotate(element, (x[i], y[i]))
```

I hope this explanation also helps.